# other than home page css file not loading in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i configure website on my local host using **XAMPP** but other rhan homepage the **css** files not loding

**my .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://hypertradeproject.local/';
```

on home page css link like.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

when i open page source they are like

> http://hypertradeproject.local/assets/css/bootstrap.css

and on all other pages they are like i.e

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

when i open page source they are like

> http://hypertradeproject.local/site/cat_one_subcat/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   http://hypertradeproject.local/login/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
>
> they have to be like
>
> http://hypertradeproject.local/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   http://hypertradeproject.local/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

im new to codeigniter. any suggestions.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working heres the two diffrent ways.

Either place `base_url` **(base url whic we defign in  `application/config/config.php`)** at the start in `href` like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

or just add `"/"` start of `href` like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

First load `url` helper in `application/config/autoload.php` using

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

OR you can load `url` helper in `controller` using `$this->load->helper('url');`

then link your css files like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

> $config['root_dir']= "/"; Add this line in your
>   application/config/config.php file

```html
then inlcude your css file like this
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->config->item('root_dir')?>assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->config->item('root_dir')?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add site_url in front of path.

Thanks

Comment: you are absolutely right .or add "/" in front of path.